# Where to ask questions about computer settings?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a problem with my environment variables(I kind of messed up the path and I need the standard variable). I don't know where to ask this question. I was thinking about Super User but I wasn't sure. Where should I ask this question?

Comment: Have a search of Superuser to see if similar questions exist before asking. As a hint though, [there is already an Environmental Variables](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/environment-variables) tag on there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most cases [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the place to ask.  There are also sites specifically for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), and [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) questions, so you might try one of those if they apply.  If it's an environment variable specifically for a programming tool (e.g., JAVA_HOME) you should be able to ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).